# Как нажать на кнопку OK в текстовом диалоге?

Tags: ubuntu

Подскажите, почему при установке postfix на ubuntu, открывается окно с конфигурацией где надо нажать OK. Нажать не получается, как не жму Enter, установка дальше не продолжается, а закрываю окно, установка естественно останавливается и ничего не установлено в итоге

Comment: а помимо "ОК" в окне больше ничего не написано? :)

Comment: нет конечно)

Comment: если нажать Esc, то откроется окно выбора, нажимаю любой выбор, опять текст, OK, и не нажимается

Comment: так а тексте что написано? или там не для вас пишут?

Comment: /sarcasm on: а что, сам не угадаешь ЧТО там написано? =)))))

Comment: я бы подумал, что ЕУЛА, но в постфиксе вроде не должно

еще может просить придумать пасс для системной учетки, но тоже в постфиксе вроде не должно

Comment: ну такими угадайками там вообще все что угодно может быть, начиная от прав пользователя под которым ставится до тупо кривой убунты или старой версии убунты... а вообще это все челябинский метеорит!

Comment: мне больше не понятно, зачем самому пытаться почтосервак под^W сломать

Answer (score 2):

> Нажать не получается

навигация между элементами диалога осуществляется клавишей <kbd>tab</kbd>.